# Integration and calculating the area under a trig function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

So my assignment states the following:

$$\text{Let}\;\;f(x) = -\sin(x),\,\;\text{where}\;\,x \in \left[-\dfrac{\pi}{4}, \dfrac{\pi}{6}\right]$$

---

Ok, so I know the forum isn't here to do my homework, but I do need some help in the area I'm getting stuck in. Now I know this somehow relates to the Unit circle, but I'm not sure how to use it.

My best guess is that I somehow have to figure out the $x$ values to use so I can calculate the definite integral. Now how do I use the $-\sin(x)$ function to find those values on the unit circle? Or do I instead use the cosine function (anti-derivate) to find the $x$ values?

It's a multiple choice question and I've come close to the answer, but not the actual answer.

What am I missing?

---

This is what I have so far. I get the $F$ of $-\sin x$ which I believe is $cos x.$ Then I do the following

$$F\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right) - F\left(-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right) - \cos\left(-\frac{\pi}{4}\right) =\frac{\sqrt 3}{2} - \left(-\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} \right) $$

Is that correct?

Comment: Have you sketched a graph of the function? Since $-\sin x$ is _below_ the $x$ axis when $x$ is between $0$ and $\pi/6$, you will first need to figure out exactly what the question means by "the area under" the function in that case.

Comment: Well the question basically states "The area between the graph of f and the x-axis is given by " and the the function and a choice of answers.

As a side note, when they ask for the total area I assume it also counts for the area when the grpah dips under the x-axis?

Comment: If the question says "**between** $f$ and the axis", then this is important information that should go in the question. You're going to get wrong answers when you ask for the area "**under** $f$".

Comment: Thanks. Will make sure to better articulate in future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for the area *under* the curve $f(x) = - \sin x$ between the values $x = -\pi/4$ and $x = \pi/6$.

$$\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/6} -\sin x \,dx$$

**But** if you're looking for area between the curve $f(x) = -\sin x$ and the $x$-axis, then you need to divide the integral into two integrals if you are to find "absolute area" between the curve and the x-axis, which is the curve/line $y = 0$, since on the interval $(0, \pi/6)$, $-\sin x < 0$.

[image]

Close up of positive region (above x-axis) and negative region (below x-axis).
[image]
So if you want area between the curve and the x-axis (i.e., the line $y = 0$), you need to integrate the following two integrals, and in each, we take the top curve and subtract the bottom curve. For the first integral, $-\sin x > 0$ so the integrand is $-\sin x - 0$, and in the second integral, $0 > -\sin x$, so we need for the integrand to be $0 - (-\sin x)$:

$$\begin{align}\text{Area}\;& =\;\int_{-\pi/4}^0 (-\sin x - 0)\,dx + \int_0^{\pi/6}(0 - (-\sin x))\,dx \\ \\ 
& = \int_{-\pi/4}^0 -\sin x\,dx \quad +\quad  \int_0^{\pi/6}\sin x\,dx \\ \\ 
& = \cos x\Big|_{-\pi/4}^0 \quad + \quad -\cos x\Big|_0^{\pi/6}\\ \\ 
& = \left(1 - \frac{\sqrt 2}2\right) - \left(\frac{\sqrt 3}2 - 1\right)\\ \\
& = 2 - \frac 12(\sqrt 3 + \sqrt 2) \end{align}$$

Comment: Very nice +1 . How do you do these graphs?

Comment: Thanks, @DonAntonio! - Credit to WolframAlpha!

Comment: Excellent thank you! Will give this a try. Your explanation makes sense. How should I have identified that I would need to split it into two integrals though? Would like to know for future reference to avoid mistakes.

Comment: ***Graph*** the relevant curves to see what you're working with! When you are given "between the curve and the $x$-axis", that means between the curve and the line $y = 0$. Sometimes you'll need to find the area between $f(x)$ and g(x), and then you need to determine which curve is on top. The intervals of integration occur at the point of intersection of the two curves: here, $-\sin x $ intersects $y = 0$ at $x = 0$, so we divide the intervals of integration into two: $-\pi/4$ to $0$, then $0$ to $-\pi/6$.

Comment: Nice answer, +1. Just a small typo: "area between the curve $f(x)=−\sin x$ and the $y$-axis". It should be $x$-axis, right?

Comment: Again, thank you for the great feedback. I'm just not 100% clear on why -sin x is used when x is < 0 and sin x when x > 0. 

On other examples the only time I've had to worry about the absolute value of a function when it was clearly stated. Is it something I should check for when x < 0 on any graph or when f(x) < 0?

Comment: The function $-\sin x$ gives positive output for the negative x in this interval, just as the function $y = -x$ outputs positive values (above x axis) when given negative x values. In the second integral, we evaluate between the top curve (y = 0) and the bottom curve $y = -\sin x$: that means we subtract to bottom from the top curve, and $0 - (-\sin x) = \sin x$. Nothing mysterious about it. If the answer's been helpful, please feel free to *accept* it: just click on the $\checkmark$ to the left of the answer. You can only accept one answer per question though.

Comment: Awesome. I think I understand. You have no idea how frustrated I was with this and how long I worked on it.

Comment: Sometimes we learn the most from the problems we struggle the most with. It's part of the learning process...we struggle, hit our heads against a wall, but then things fall into place...AHA! That kind of learning sticks with you!

Comment: Ok, I think I need some further clarification because I don't understand when to take into consideration when to use the absolute value of the function when it dips under the x-axis.

In other definite integral questions, they simple calculate the value without changing it into absolute values first. As if the negative area is subtracted from the positive area to give a net area above the curve.

Answer (score 2):

Area under any function $f(x)$: $$A=\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)|dx$$
$\sin x$ is negative between $-\pi/4$ and $0$, so $|-\sin x|=-\sin x$ for this interval.
For $x$ between $0$ and $\pi/6$ you have $|-\sin x|=\sin x$.

Thus, your area is:
$$ A=\int_{-\pi/4}^{0}(-\sin{x})dx +\int_{0}^{\pi/6}\sin{x} {dx}$$

And i think you can solve from here on.